# Connecting to matic mumbai via websocket

Tags: web3js, polygon, websocket

I try to connect to mumbai testnet via websocket to listen to blockchain events:

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://rpc-mumbai.matic.today"));
```

However, I get the following errors:
[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Do I need to get an API key to be able to connect via websocket?

Comment: It seems a network issue. Try with another provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use an api key and another provider:

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://polygon-testnet.blastapi.io/my-api-key"));
```

where `my-api-key` is obtained from blastapi.io.